# How to save ZAProxy Options?

Tags: zap

I am using ZAProxy 2.7.0 on RHEL7 with a smart card that holds a client certificate to the site I am trying to use access through ZAProxy. Using the smart card requires setting some PKCS#11 values under Tools/Options/Certificate, especially selecting a driver, PIN code, and setting it Active.

Unfortunately, these values do not persist between ZAProxy runs. I have seen that other options do persist, but not these ones. I would also like to use ZAProxy in headless mode - in that case I cannot even set these options (at least I haven't found a way).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's getting closer, you can now do this for pcks#12 certs, using a weekly build or the next release. It adds that functionality both to the cli and web API: https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-core-help/pull/227/files

If smart card support is important to you I'd suggest opening a feature request: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/issues/new?labels=enhancement&template=Feature_request.md

Comment: Thank you, submitted FR: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/issues/5423